# cache-control headers on openshift

Tags: python, apache, openshift, wsgi

How can I setup cache-control headers on openshift apache server? I using python 2.7 cartridge (with wsgi and django) and I can't find how can modify apache settings. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use .htaccess to set cache-control headers on OpenShift. See [using cache in .htaccess to speed up your site](http://www.chicagostyleseo.com/2010/04/googles-need-for-speed-use-cache-and-htaccess-to-speed-up-your-site/) for sample cache-control code. For an example of using .htaccess within an OpenShift Python application repo, check out [using basic auth with Python](https://github.com/OpenShift-Cookbook/chapter8-htaccess-recipe).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I couldn't setup in this way. I put a .htaccess file into my repo root directory (next to the wsgi.py, setup.py) and it has no affects. My .htaccess content is: 
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

Comment: The .htaccess file should probably go in your `wsgi` or `wsgi/projectname` directory.